# using oPort option in Apache commons SFTP

Tags: apache, sftp, apache-commons-net

I have a sftp server which i can connect manually using the command below

sftp -oport=4022 user@xxxxxx.com

but I am finding difficulty in doing the same with apache commons vfs.

Below is the method I am using to establish connection to the sftp server. But it not working and fails with the error "org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException: Could not connect to SFTP server at xxxxxx.com"

```
public boolean connect(String host, String login, String password,
                       int port) throws Exception {

    //If the client is already connected, disconnect
    if (command != null) {
        disconnect();
    }
    FileSystemOptions fso = new FileSystemOptions();

    try {
        SftpFileSystemConfigBuilder.getInstance().setStrictHostKeyChecking(fso,
                                                                           "no");

        session =
                SftpClientFactory.createConnection(host, port, login.toCharArray(),
                                                   password.toCharArray(),
                                                   fso);

        System.out.println("pass");
        Channel channel = session.openChannel("ssh");
        channel.connect();
        command = (ChannelSftp)channel;

    } catch (FileSystemException e) {
        throw e;
       // return false;
    }
    return command.isConnected();
}
```

Please help me with this

Comment: Show us how are you calling the `connect`. Also the exception should have more details in `.getCause()` (or even better, include complete call stack)

Comment: @MartinPrikryl, I am not able to paste stack trace in the comments as it is too long. Let me know how to share it with you please?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl: A quick update. I deleted the remote server key from the known_host file and tried the above code and it is succesfully able to connect. Still not sure how this worked. but it is resolved now.

Comment: Please close your question.